# Switch Case always falls through to default

Tags: php, switch-statement, control-flow

It appears there's something wrong in my Switch Case logic as it always falls through to default.

```
echo $platform;

switch($platform){

    case "Gaming / Xbox 360 Games":
        $internalPlatform = "MXT";
        break;
    case "Gaming / Nintendo DS Games":
        $internalPlatform = "NDS";
        break;
    default:
        $internalPlatform = "MISC";
        break;

}

echo $internalPlatform;
```

Where `$platform` = "Gaming / Xbox 360 Games" and `$internalPlatform` = "MISC".

Any ideas on what is causing it to fall through?

Comment: what gives you `var_dump($platform);`?

Comment: do a `var_dump($platform)` before the switch-case to verify it has the value you are expecting. Remember, php is also case sensitive. So it may be something simple like a single work not caps.

Comment: Trim newlines and other invisible stuff!

Comment: I think that he has forgot to define $platform as he said he did

Comment: I typed out the $platform set and used "XBox" in my platform, took me a minute to realize my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the logic above.

Thanks to Paolo for pointing out to strip tags & invisibles out the variable. var_dump helped me find that out!

Answer (score 0):

Mybe you missed a prefix or suffix space
Try to comper the output of this echo with the case string.
    echo "$platform";